# Angular 9 with jsPDF module : Type 'typeof jsPDF' has no construct signatures

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, angular9, angular-cli-v9

Angular 9
Module which has issue jsPDF (installed types + packages itself)

When doing ng serve it works
When doing ng build --prod , it has errors

```
ERROR in src/app/xxx/xxxx.componentomponent.ts:52:27 - error TS2351: This expression is not constructable.
  Type 'typeof jsPDF' has no construct signatures.

52       let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
                             ~~~~~

  src/app/xxx/xxxx.component.ts:7:1
    7 import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Type originates at this import. A namespace-style import cannot be called or constructed, and will cause a failure at runtime. Consider using a default import or import require here instead.
```

tsconfig file has "esModuleInterop": true,

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "fullTemplateTypeCheck": true,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true
  }
}
```

I import the module like this :

```
**import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';**
```

Use it like this inside my class :

```
 generatePDF() {
    var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');
    html2canvas(data).then(canvas => {
      var imgWidth = 208;
      var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width;
      const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
      let pdf = **new jsPDF**('p', 'mm', 'a4');
      var position = 0;
      pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight)
      pdf.save('skill-set.pdf');
    });
  }
```

I also tried to add the module js files in scripts section of angular.json

```
  "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              **"node_modules/jspdf/dist/jspdf.min.js"**
            ]
```

Comment: Try installing jsPDF as a node module instead: `npm install -S jspdf` and remove yhe script import from `angular.json`

Comment: I've initially done it with npm install jspdf --save 
Then tried like a module

Comment: Dis you also install `@types/jspdf`?

Comment: @David yes I did.  I found out what was the issue, I sent couple parameters as I found in one article on web . **new jsPDF**('p', 'mm', 'a4'); Removing parameters , solved the issue

Answer (score 23):

(tested in angular 10, so I guess this fix is for newer angular versions)

instead of this :

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

write this :

```
import jspdf from 'jspdf';
```

[**Watch out ! both `jspdf` in 2nd line are in small letter**]

then your

```
let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
```

would work too, just change all to small letter (**you must import in small letter like my 2nd import line before doing this**)

```
let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4');
```

Answer (score 8):

I setup a fresh angular 10 project and was able to use `jspdf`.

1. Create new Angular app

```sh
> npx @angular/cli new pdf-viewer --strict --defaults true
```

2. Install `jspdf` package from npm registry

```sh
> cd pdf-viewer
> npm install jspdf --save
> npm install @types/jspdf --save-dev
```

[image]

3. Update `tsconfig.base.json`. Add `allowSyntheticDefaultImports` inside `compilerOptions`

```
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
```

4. Add some `jspdf` code to test in `src/app/app.component.ts`

```js
import { Component, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import jsPDF from 'jspdf';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'pdf-viewer';

  constructor() {
    this.generatePDF();
  }

  private generatePDF(): void {
    const doc = new jsPDF();

    doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10);
    doc.save('a4.pdf');
  }
}
```

5. Launch angular application and navigate to `http://localhost:4200`. You will notice that `a4.pdf` gets downloaded as soon as we open the webpage. Open the PDF file to verify the integrity of the file.

```sh
> npm start
```

Comment: I figured out was was wrong. 
In my code , I pass some parameters "new jsPDF**('p', 'mm', 'a4') " as I found in some of the examples . This was actually the issue. Once I changed to **new jsPDF**() declaration , error was gone

Answer (score 2):

Just import like this:

```
import { jsPDF } from 'jspdf';

// and Initialize JSPDF
var doc = new jsPDF("p", "mm", "a4");
```

This works for me.

Answer (score -1):

instead of this :

```
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
```

write this :

```
import JSPDF from 'jspdf';
```

then your

```
let pdf = new JSPDF.jsPDF();
```